# 各配列の要素の最大値取得

Tags: python3

下記の多重配列がありまして

```
result_list = [[100, 100, 500], [200, 20, 20], [20, 20, 20], [20, 20, 20]]
```

上記の各配列の最大値要素を取得したいのですがどのように
行えばよろしいでしょうか？
補足で、配列数は毎回異なります。

```
# 求める出力結果
result = [[500], [200], [20], [20]]
```

お分かりの方がいましたら、ご教示願います。

Answer (score 1):

[max()](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/functions.html#max)を使ってリスト内包表記と組み合わせれば出来るでしょう。

```
result = [[max(l)] for l in result_list]
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。
思った通りの出力結果になりました。
ご回答ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

`numpy` を使っても良いのであれば以下になります。

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> result_list = [[100, 100, 500], [200, 20, 20], [20, 20, 20], [20, 20, 20]]
>>> np.max(result_list, axis=1).reshape(-1, 1)
array([[500],
       [200],
       [ 20],
       [ 20]])
```

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
このやり方は知らなかったので、すごく参考になりました。